# What is the cause of HFValidationError in this code and how do I resolve this error?

Tags: android-studio, python-3.8, chaquopy, gpt-2

My python code in Chaquopy android studio Project:

```
import torch as tc
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2Model



def generate_text(txt):
    """
    Generate chat
    https://huggingface.co/gpt2
    """

    #Load Model files
    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('assets/') #This line causing error
    model = GPT2Model.from_pretrained('assets/')
    #Move moel to GPU if avilable
    device = tc.device("cuda" if tc.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model.to(device)

    encoded_input = tokenizer(txt, return_tensors='pt')
    output = model(**encoded_input)

    return str(output)
```

Now it is showing following error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chaquopy_130application, PID: 4867
    com.chaquo.python.PyException: HFValidationError: Repo id must use alphanumeric chars or '-', '_', '.', '--' and '..' are forbidden, '-' and '.' cannot start or end the name, max length is 96: 'assets/'.
        at <python>.huggingface_hub.utils._validators.validate_repo_id(_validators.py:164)
        at <python>.huggingface_hub.utils._validators._inner_fn(_validators.py:110)
        at <python>.huggingface_hub.utils._deprecation.inner_f(_deprecation.py:103)
        at <python>.transformers.file_utils.get_list_of_files(file_utils.py:2103)
        at <python>.transformers.tokenization_utils_base.get_fast_tokenizer_file(tokenization_utils_base.py:3486)
        at <python>.transformers.tokenization_utils_base.from_pretrained(tokenization_utils_base.py:1654)
        at <python>.pythonScript.generate_text(pythonScript.py:30)
```

I have put all files of 124M GPT-2 model  *checkpoint*, *encoder.json*, *hparams.json*, *model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001*, *model.ckpt.index*, *model.ckpt.meta*, *vocab.bpe* files inside of 'assets' folder.

[image: file structure]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`from_pretrained`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.30.0/en/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained) documentation is not entirely clear about how it distinguishes huggingface repository names from local paths, although all the local path examples end with a slash.

In any case, when loading data files with Chaquopy, you must always use absolute paths, as it says in [the FAQ](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-data). So assuming your "assets" directory is at the same level as the Python code, you can do this:

```
from os.path import dirname
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(f'{dirname(__file__)}/assets/')
```