# Error using dreambooth on collab: HFValidationError: Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name

Tags: huggingface, stable-diffusion

currently trying to run dreambooth on google collab with another model - https://huggingface.co/Lykon/DreamShaper

everything seems to run okie however in the last step: PART 3.0: Configure and load your model, ready to create AI images, when i run that i am getting this error:

```
HFValidationError: Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name': 
'/content/drive/MyDrive/stable_diffusion_weights/x_KimeKoos__orbetter__yourname/1000'. Use `repo_type` argument if 
needed.
```

I am using this as a repo - Lykon/DreamShaper however i am not however why i keep getting this error. also this error is not consistent.

Here is the google collab file - https://colab.research.google.com/github/steinhaug/stable-diffusion/blob/main/Dreambooth_Colab_edition_for_people_in_a_hurry_fp16.ipynb#scrollTo=32gYIDDR1aCp

Comment: Check this approach : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76500504/what-is-the-cause-of-hfvalidationerror-in-this-code-and-how-do-i-resolve-this-er

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I'm having the same problem using Dreambooth extension in AUTOMATIC1111 on Colab